# Moving a set of point, except one. And figuring out where the missing one should approximately be.

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

[image: Example image]

I'm trying to automate workflow, but my math is not so good.

I know a bunch of points, for example A,B,C and P, (in reality about 20 to 50). Then I move A,B,C and need to figure out where P should approximately be. A,B and C does not move the exact same, and might be tighter or more spread out.

This is in 3D-space if it makes a difference.

Edit: additional example : The red ball should move into the right partial cylinder. The vertices are the points.[image: Additional example]

Comment: Do you know if there are rules that determine where P should be? For instance, P being the centroid of the polyhedron whose vertices are the other points?

Comment: I added an additional image to try and explain more specifics.